# Tooltips get hidden behind dropdown lists? How can you avoid this? (IE6)

Tags: asp.net, html, css, vb.net

I have a label with a tooltip attribute for rollover effect.  This works all great.  However, it seems to get hidden behind any dropdown lists that are nearby.  I have tried adjusting the z-index, without any luck.  This issue does not appear in firefox, and I have not tested it in later versions of IE.

I realize this is probably due to IE6s poor css standards-compatibility, but how can I get around this?

Answer (score 1):

IE6 has a know error that selects always end up the highest in the z order...

Custom select control optional?

Have a look at [this](http://codeasp.net/forums/asp-net-topics/Clent%20Side%20Web%20Development/104/please-help-issue-with-dropdown-in-ie6)

Another idea is to use the ajaxtoolkit autocomplete?

Comment: I am using asp.net with vb.net (I suppose I should have tagged it as such, I'll do that now).  I have not done this before, but I'll do my research.  Thanks for the tip

Answer (score 1):

Not the best because it requires javascript/jQuery library, but there's a workaround:

http://dhtmlgrounds.wordpress.com/2008/12/23/ie6-select-box-z-index-bug/

Answer (score 0):

The select dropdown in IE6 is implemented as a Windows control, so the browser isn't really drawing it.  Thus, it doesn't support features like z-index.  One possible solution is to hide all select boxes on the page when you show your tool-tip.  Another option is a custom dropdown, which you can find in libraries like Ext.

Answer (score 0):

As [astander](https://stackoverflow.com/users/144424/astander) and [MikeWyatt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/182786/mikewyatt) said, selects in IE are topmost. There are two paths to work-around this problem:

1. Use a custom select box, rendered with divs, etc. This is rather cumbersome, since you won't be able to replicate all of the drop-down functionality.
2. Place an `<IFRAME>` under the tooltip (tooltip z-index > iframe z-index). This will work-around the problem, yet you have to worry about the positioning of the iframe *overlay*.